# Fizz-Buzzify a String

Tags: code-golf, string

You will be given a String that only contains letters of the English Alphabet, both lowercase and uppercase (ASCII 65-90 and 97-122). Your task is to output the Fizz-Buzzified version of the String.

#### How to Fizz-Buzzify a String?

- Each letter that has an even index in the English alphabet (the alphabet **must** be 1-indexed: `a->1,b->2,...,z->26`) will be turned into `fizz` if it is lowercase and `FIZZ` if it is uppercase (`f -> fizz, F -> FIZZ`).
- Each letter that has an odd index in the English alphabet will be turned into `buzz` if it is lowercase, and `BUZZ` if it is uppercase (`e -> buzz, E -> BUZZ`).
- Let's have an example, to illustrate the algorithm, using the string `CodeGolf` (spaces added for clarity):

  ```
  "C o d e G o l f" ->  "BUZZ buzz fizz buzz BUZZ buzz fizz fizz"
   ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
   1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0       (1 is odd index, 0 is even index)
  ```
- If it is more convenient for your language, you may also leave *single spaces* between the groups (`fizz, buzz, FIZZ, BUZZ`). Hence, a result like `fizzBUZZbuzzbuzz` can also be returned as `fizz BUZZ buzz buzz`. Other separators are not allowed.

---

## Test Cases:

```
Input  ->  Output 

"egg"          ->  "buzzbuzzbuzz"
"CodeGolf"     ->  "BUZZbuzzfizzbuzzBUZZbuzzfizzfizz"
"Reset"        ->  "FIZZbuzzbuzzbuzzfizz"
"ATOM"         ->  "BUZZFIZZBUZZBUZZ"
"yOuArEgReAt"  ->  "buzzBUZZbuzzBUZZfizzBUZZbuzzFIZZbuzzBUZZfizz"
```

---

- [Any standard method for I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) can be used.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- You are only allowed to take input in your language's native String type. The same applies for output.
- You can assume that the input will not be empty.
- Shortest code in bytes in every language wins. Good Luck and Fizz-Buzz!

Comment: [Sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13075#13075)

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
ＦθＦ⎇﹪℅ι²buzz¦fizz⎇№αι↥κκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXndgCJR33t73euetTSem7noU1JpVVVh5alZVZVAYUftUw7t/HczkdtS8/tOrfr/383oLATUAEA) Originally inspired by @CarlosAlejo. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by looping over the letters of fizz/buzz instead of assigning to a temporary. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ          Loop over the input (i = loop variable)
  Ｆ         Choose and loop over the word (k = loop variable)
   ⎇        Ternary
    ﹪℅ι²    If i has an odd ASCII code
    buzz
    fizz
            Print (implicit)
  ⎇         Ternary
   №αι      If i is an uppercase letter
    ↥κ      Uppercase(k)
     κ      k
```

Comment: I finally got to understand your solution. I thought that `Ordinal(i)` returned the position of the `i` char in its original string, but it returns its ASCII value (character code). Very clever solution, I still need to improve a lot my Charcoal skills!

Comment: How you do this in Charcoal in only 24 bytes...

Comment: In which encoding is this 24 bytes?

Comment: @Ruslan In Charcoal's [custom code page](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page).

Answer (score 6):

## C#, 92 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>string.Concat(a.Select(x=>x%2<1?x<97?"FIZZ":"fizz":x<97?"BUZZ":"buzz"))
```

Comment: Posted at practically the same time but you saved a byte to my solution by ordering the ternary the shorter way +1

Comment: @TheLethalCoder ahh, sorry about that.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about we posted 12 seconds apart! And yours is shorter!

Comment: Will C# let you use `x%2` directly as a boolean, without needing the `<1` part? If so, you may be able to save some bytes that way.

Comment: @BrianJ No it doesn't do it implicitly

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>73</s> 69 bytes

4 bytes thanks to ovs.

```python
lambda s:"".join("fbFBiuIUzzZZzzZZ"[(c<"a")*2+ord(c)%2::4]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSklJLys/M09DKS3JzSmz1DO0qioqCoSVojWSbZQSlTS1jLTzi1I0kjVVjaysTGLT8osUkhUy8xSKNf8XFGXmlWikaSilpqcraWpywfnO@Smp7vk5aSiCQanFqSUoIo4h/r4oApX@pY5FrulBqY4ghf8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>105</s> <s>100</s> <s>94</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i:s.getBytes())System.out.print(i%2<1?i>90?"fizz":"FIZZ":i>90?"buzz":"BUZZ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4xa8MwEIV3/4rDUJCHiKZbndTBCW3pEAJJu6R0UGxJyLElY50CTvBvd4VjKHTzLQffe@/eFezCZqbmusjPfe1OpcogK5m1sGVKwy0AGKlFhn5djMqh8ho5YKO0/P4B1kgbDVaAwt@jDlVJhdMZKqPpxmjrKt4s74EExEtvZ8lNmIYojaBiSyXHdYvckig6tBZ5RY1DWns/EvXwtJyvVPL8uAqFul7DOHz7OB7D@I5ObkDrL4@iRdfDMItgeEdQlmW8RhJyKb08wP8NpSaj8mffmJy/m1JMyey55TglkH7utlP87c6lzavc83Ss6YKu/wU)

Much golfable, very bytes, so Java!

Very golfed by @KevinCruijssen by 9 bytes!

Comment: I thought that maybe streams would make this shorter, so I wrote one. `s->s.join("",s.chars().mapToObj(i->i>90?i%2<1?"fizz":"buzz":i%2<1?"FIZZ":"BUZZ").toArray(String[]::new));` Alas, it's 105 chars long :( If only they could add the `join` directly on the stream or integrate a `toList`, actually, anything sensible would be good.

Comment: Printing directly instead of returning a String is 6 bytes shorter, and using `getBytes()` instead of `toCharArray()` is an additional 3 bytes shorter: [`s->{for(int i:s.getBytes())System.out.print(i>90?i%2<1?"fizz":"buzz":i%2<1?"FIZZ":"BUZZ");}`](https://tio.run/##lY4xa8MwEIV3/4rDUJCHiLZbk9TBCW3pEAJJu6R0UGRJyLUlY50CTvBvd1XXUOjmWx689727K9iZzWwtTJF/9bU/lZoDL5lzsGXawDUCGF2HDIOcrc6hChk5YKON@vgE1iiXDChAEfZRj7qk0huO2hq6scb5SjTL30IK8rF3s/QqbUO0QdBzR5XAdYvCkSQ5tA5FRa1HWgceiU4fblf65n55t4qlvlzieXzyPzJ6z6/HY/DW70GSRdfDMIto@EdSxrmokcRCqRAP5v8TpSFj8odvbC5ebCmndPbCCZxSyN522yl8u/NZ86T2IhvPdFHXfwM)

Comment: You forgot the additional 3 bytes by changing `toCharArray()` to `getBytes()`. :)

Comment: I clicked before your edit and didn't see it afterwards ;) Also, I just thought about it before seeing your comment xD

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 75 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;++s)printf(*s>90?*s%2?"buzz":"fizz":*s%2?"BUZZ":"FIZZ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBC4IwHMXP7VPIQNimgnirgWJR0SEEqUs3W5sJpeJUSPGz/zP10rs83o/HTzipEACKiGdSMU17VVSEM80tS9OyyvJaEab9tRswbXoBvjddhzdYZb@a0fZ6u43ocBqL8gHeSZYTYbd0UrKW9wgZY2azZbWc9mi1uLHpudpwfAPbrKV8Ok5n8jfLptYE44UMCA0AMk1hVzzksXgpiKWWNYSX6AyfqAmrfRrLsP4C)

Answer (score 4):

## [Plain English](https://github.com/Folds/english), <s>820</s> <s>632</s> 610 bytes

[Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487) suggested eliminating an unneeded error trap, which saved 22 bytes.

```
A fizzy string is a string.
To convert a s string to a z fizzy string:
Clear the z.
Slap a r rider on the s.
Loop.
If the r's source's first is greater than the r's source's last, exit.
Put the r's source's first's target in a b byte.
If the b is not any letter, bump the r; repeat.
Put "FIZZ" in a t string.
If the b is d, put "BUZZ" in the t.
If the b is _, lowercase the t.
Append the t to the z.
Bump the r.
Repeat.
To decide if a b byte is d:
Put the b in a n number.
If the n is odd, say yes.
Say no.
To decide if a b byte is _:
Put the b in a c byte.
Lowercase the c.
If the c is the b, say yes.
Say no.
```

Ungolfed code:

```
A fizzy string is a string.

To convert a string to a fizzy string:
  Clear the fizzy string.
  Slap a rider on the string.
  Loop.
    If the rider's source's first is greater than the rider's source's last, exit.
    Put the rider's source's first's target in a byte.
    If the byte is not any letter, bump the rider; repeat.
    Put "FIZZ" in another string.
    If the byte is odd, put "BUZZ" in the other string.
    If the byte is lower case, lowercase the other string.
    Append the other string to the fizzy string.
    Bump the rider.
  Repeat.

To decide if a byte is odd:
  Put the byte in a number.
  If the number is odd, say yes.
  Say no.

To decide if a byte is lower case:
  Privatize the byte.
  Lowercase the byte.
  If the byte is the original byte, say yes.
  Say no.
```

The Plain English IDE is available at [github.com/Folds/english](https://github.com/Folds/english).  The IDE runs on Windows.  It compiles to 32-bit x86 code.

Comment: "You can assume that the input will not be empty." so I think you can drop `If the s is "", exit.`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder -- Thank you.  It turns out that the trap was not needed even if s was empty.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
smr<d\a@c"fizzbuzz"4C
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smr%3Cd%5Ca%40c%22fizzbuzz%224C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22egg%22%0A%22CodeGolf%22%0A%22Reset%22%0A%22ATOM%22%0A%22yOuArEgReAt%22&debug=0).

Comment: O_o 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 97 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>string.Concat(s.Select(c=>"fizzbuzzFIZZBUZZ".Substring(c%2*4+(c>96?0:8),2)))
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but can't you use `c%2>1?c>96?"fizz":"buzz":...`

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/./g,c=>['BUZZ','buzz','FIZZ','fizz'][parseInt(c,36)%2*2|c>'Z'])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/./g,c=>['BUZZ','buzz','FIZZ','fizz'][parseInt(c,36)%2*2|c>'Z'])

console.log(f("egg"        )) // "buzzbuzzbuzz"
console.log(f("CodeGolf"   )) // "BUZZbuzzfizzbuzzBUZZbuzzfizzfizz"
console.log(f("Reset"      )) // "FIZZbuzzbuzzbuzzfizz"
console.log(f("ATOM"       )) // "BUZZFIZZBUZZBUZZ"
console.log(f("yOuArEgReAt")) // "buzzBUZZbuzzBUZZfizzBUZZbuzzFIZZbuzzBUZZfizz"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
“=%“Ƈ×»ẋ13Œu;$ɓØWiÐ€ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4oCcPSXigJzGh8OXwrvhuosxM8WSdTskyZPDmFdpw5Digqzhu4v///9lZ2c)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>40</strike> 36 bytes

```
Ｆθ¿№αι¿﹪⌕αι²FIZZ¦BUZZ¿﹪⌕βι²fizz¦buzz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXndhza/6hl2rmN53Ye2v9@56pHPVPB7E1unlFRh5Y5hQJJmPgmkHhaZlXVoWVJpVVV//8756ekuufnpAEA)

Explanation:

```
Ｆθ                                      for every char i in the input:
   ¿№αι                                    if i is found in the uppercase alphabet
       ¿﹪⌕αι²                             if i is an even uppercase char
              FIZZ¦BUZZ                    print "FIZZ" or else "BUZZ"
                       ¿﹪⌕βι²             if i is an even lowercase char
                              fizz¦buzz    print "fizz" or else "buzz"
```

An alternative with the same byte count:

```
ＡfizzφＡbuzzχＦθ¿№αι¿﹪⌕αι²↥φ↥χ¿﹪⌕βι²φχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noVpmVVV59uAjKRSIKP9/Z5l53Yc2v@oZdq5jed2Htr/fueqRz1TwexNj9qWnm8DEe1w8U0g8fNt59v//3fOT0l1z89JAwA) ([Verbose version](https://tio.run/##Zc69DsIgEMDxvU9x6cQldHHtZJroZOLiA1DglIRwFcShL49I/Eoc@d3dP@iLipqVL2WbkjsH0ZNb114C4di9ac6NdCXiCOKKHYAjEBPncBNKOsT2PrDJnsXOBdNUburgGF1dOi2LjVolKwhx/ENd8RX9jczPCHwr9DmtnyllYmP37KkM9zIk/wA))

- 4 bytes saved thanks to Neil!

Comment: Use `Count` or `Ordinal` respectively instead of `Find` to save you some bytes.

Comment: The entire `if` counts as a single statement so you don't need the `{}`s. I also saved a byte by moving the `Uppercase` inside a `Ternary`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DKS2zqkpJRyFN05oLJpRUChZKBgql5RcpaBRqKgQUZeaVaISkFuUlFlVqOOeXAnmJOgqZmjoKoQUFqUXJicWpcGnf/JTSnHwN/6KUzLzEHA2QIiMgTgbZAqSJUqZp/f@/c35Kqnt@Ttp/3bL/usU5AA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: Better still, `Ｆθ«Ａ⎇﹪℅ι²buzz¦fizzχ⎇№αι↥χχ` for 26 bytes. (Deverbosifier doesn't like this version.)

Comment: @Neil Thank you very much, but I can't even understand your last version, so I cannot take credit for it, I would feel as it is not my own answer. I'd be honored to be outgolfed by you if you write your own post. :-)

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 68 bytes

```
<vv?("^"$%2:;?(0:i
v\?\"zzif"
v \\"zzub"
v \ "ZZIF"
v  \"ZZUB"
\oooo
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36aszF5DKU5JRdXIytpew8Aqk6ssxj5GqaoqM02Jq0whBsQsTQIzFZSiojzdQEyFGCAz1EmJKyYfCP7/D0vNKUstcUrNyan0ScwrSS3KK85ILMoGAA), or watch it at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

(But look at [Aaron's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128653/66104) which is 13 bytes shorter!)

If you're not familiar with ><>, there's a fish that swims through the code in 2D, and the edges wrap. The symbols `>`, `<`, `^` and `v` set the direction of the fish, `/` and `\` are mirrors that reflect it, and `?` means "do the next instruction if the top thing on the stack is non-zero, otherwise jump over the next instruction".

In the first line, the fish takes a character of input (`i`); if it's -1 for EOF, it halts (`:0(?;`); it gets the charcode mod 2 (`:2%$`); and it pushes a 1 or 0 on the stack depending on whether the charcode is less than or greater than the charcode of "^" (`"^"(`). The next three lines redirect the fish to the right fizz/buzz string, then the last line prints it (one `o` for each character) and sends the fish back to the start.

Comment: @Aaron, that's great! I did think of that idea but couldn't get it to work. Would you like to post that as your own solution?

Comment: @Aaron, you've also found a bug in either TIO or the [online interpreter](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) — in that interpreter, `!` or `?` followed by a space just skips the space, but TIO waits until the next non-space thing to skip…

Comment: @Aaron, your submission's much better than mine, so you can post it yourself and I'll delete this one.

Comment: `!` should skips spaces AFAIK, but the online interpreter pads its codespace with spaces, which is probably what you're seeing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61160/discussion-between-aaron-and-not-a-tree).

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 55 bytes

Based on Not a tree's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128636/41881).

```
<v%2$)"^":;?(0:i
 \?v"ZZIF"
~v >"ZZUB"!
^>{:}" "*+ol1=?
```

Instead of representing the 4 possible output in the code, I only represent their capitalized versions and add 32 to the character code to get the small case equivalents.

[Try it online !](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36ZM1UhFUylOycraXsPAKpNLIca@TCkqytNNiauuTMEOyAx1UlLkirOrtqpVUlDS0s7PMbS1///fOT8l1T0/Jw0A)

Modified code for the [online interpreter](https://fishlanguage.com/playground), which pads its codespace with empty cells :

```
<v%2$)"^":;?(0:i
 \?v"ZZIF"
~v >"ZZUB"     !
^>{:}" "*+o l1=?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl5](http://www.perl.org/), 50+1 bytes

```
perl -nE'say+((FIZZ,BUZZ)x48,(fizz,buzz)x16)[unpack"C*",$_]'
```

Creates a 128-item list that maps ASCII chars to the proper code word.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
v‘FIZZÒÖ‘#yÇÉèAyåil}J?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7FHDDDfPqKjDkw5PAzKVKw@3H@48vMKx8vDSzJxaL/v//yv9Sx2LXNODUh1LAA)

**Explanation**

```
v                        # for each char y of input string
 ‘FIZZÒÖ‘#               # push the list ['FIZZ','BUZZ']
          yÇÉ            # check if y has an odd character code
             è           # use this to index into the list
              Ayåi       # if y is a member of the lowercase alphabet
                  l}     # convert to lowercase
                    J?   # unwrap from list and print
```

**Alternative 22 byte solution**

```
ÇÉAISå·+‘FIZZÒÖ‘#Dl«èJ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), <s>154</s> <s>153</s> 145 bytes

saved <s>1</s> 9 bytes thanks to [@Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```fs
let g s=
 Seq.map(fun c->match int c with
|x when x>64&&x<91->if x%2=0 then"FIZZ"else"BUZZ"
|x->if x%2=0 then"fizz"else"buzz")s
|>String.concat""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvBCoJAFEX3fsXlgWELpSKCIAWDglZB0sadDTPjgI7WPMnCfzepXbtzuOcqF9aNbcaxkgwNF3vI5D2qizZQnYUIEw91waKEsQyBp@HSA4Yez1Ja9MlmPZv1u@0yTIxC76/iBXha6HjKc5KVk7S/ToTv6T9S5v3@RbduornzMCQZP4zVkWisKBhEYzs5KwvyHSHQoNe5Sx8HfZEp03z8AA)

Comment: Save 1 byte by removing the space between `concat` and `""` on the last line

Comment: [150 bytes, although I don't know F#](https://tio.run/##XYvBCoJAFEX38xWXB4oulIoIgnTRomgtbdzZMDMO6GjNk0T8dzPatTuHe672Sdu5blkaxTDwmUChnmlb9ZEeHGSSC7QVyxrWMSTelmuBecS7Vg5jftiH4Xg6bpPcaozBLtuA14Uut7Ik1XhF5/tK@H7@G22n6dc8hpViL@a84Jd1JpWdkxUTLf2qrB0o8ITIgNTVULx8AA)

Comment: [145 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYvNCoJAFEb3PsXlgqILpSKCIGfRomgtbdzZMH@gozVXHMR3nwbatTuH73zSlcNoxxB6QaDA1Qk04l0N3ZTL2QIv2dAR12AsAYfFkE42D4sWFjw7HbPMX877khkJPj3UO6C44O3Rtih6J/D6jBQf/4U06/orXnOkwiUba@hjrKr4aHlHiGGKStICpg4hV4DirrAIXw), remove the unnecessary whitespace

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Xcoder I'm still getting used to F# and when indentation is significant!

Comment: And BTW, Welcome to PPCG! I don't know F# at all, just removed stuff to see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 67 bytes

```php
for(;$c=$argn[$i++];)echo[FIZZ,BUZZ,fizz,buzz][ord($c)%2+2*($c>Z)];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6vknJ@S6p6fk6Zk/T8tv0jDWiXZFiwTrZKprR1rrZmanJEf7eYZFaXjFAok0jKrqnSSSquqYqPzi1I0VJI1VY20jbSADLsozVjr//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 134 bytes

```
""<>{(s=Max@ToCharacterCode@#;If[96<s<123,If[EvenQ@s,c="fizz",c="buzz"]];If[64<s<91,If[EvenQ@s,c="FIZZ",c="BUZZ"]];c)&/@Characters@#}&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 89 bytes

```
s->s.chars().mapToObj(i->i%2<1?i>90?"fizz":"FIZZ":i>90?"buzz":"BUZZ").collect(joining());
```

It assumes `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-release-process/), <s>144</s> 135 bytes

```swift
func f(s:String){print(s.map{let d=Int(UnicodeScalar("\($0)")!.value);return d%2<1 ?d>90 ?"fizz":"FIZZ":d>90 ?"buzz":"BUZZ"}.joined())}
```

Un-golfed:

```swift
func f(s:String){
    print(
        s.map{
            let d=Int(UnicodeScalar("\($0)")!.value)
            return d%2 < 1 ? d > 90 ? "fizz" : "FIZZ" : d > 90 ? "buzz" : "BUZZ"
        }.joined()
    )
}
```

What I am doing is looping over each character in the string. I convert each to its ASCII value, then check to see if it is even or odd, and then check to see if it is upper or lowercase and output the matching value from the loop. I then join all the elements of the resulting array into a single string and print it.

This solution uses Swift 4, so there is no way to easily test it online yet.

Thanks to @Mr.Xcoder for saving me 9 bytes!

Comment: `error: value of type 'String' has no member 'map'`, because a String is not automatically converted to a list on runtime.

Comment: Also, that service is not free. You have to add a credit card in order to test your submission if I don't copy-paste it. Consider changing the test service.

Comment: In order to make it work, you must turn it into `$0.characters.map{...}`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Cloud 9 has a free tier, in which you only get one private workspace and unlimited public workspaces. You should be able to sign in through GitHub. I have never shared anything with it so I wasn't sure if it would work. Also, I should have mentioned I am using Swift 4, where String conforms to Collection. This mean it has a map function.

Comment: As I can see, the old function declaration is still valid in Swift 4, like `func f(s:String){...}`, hence you can save 9 bytes by using the following code, that uses `print` instead of `return`: https://pastebin.com/06kiiGaJ. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>150</s> <s>123</s> 108 bytes

```
i=ifelse
cat(i(sapply(el(strsplit(scan(,''),'')),utf8ToInt)>91,i(x%%2,'buzz','fizz'),i(x%%2,'BUZZ','FIZZ')))
```

<s>Has to be shorter using ASCII?</s> It was shorter. See edit history for old answer, which used `letters`.

Checks each letter for (1) whether it's capital or not (`>91`) and whether it's a `fizz` or a `buzz`.

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 48 bytes

**Solution:**

```
raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$
```

**Examples:**

```
q)raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$"egg"
"buzzbuzzbuzz"
q)raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$"CodeGolf"
"BUZZbuzzfizzbuzzBUZZbuzzfizzfizz"
q)raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$"Reset"
"FIZZbuzzbuzzbuzzfizz"
q)raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$"ATOM"
"BUZZFIZZBUZZBUZZ"
q)raze{@[($)`fizz`buzz x mod 2;(&)x<91;upper]}"i"$"yOuArEgReAt"
"buzzBUZZbuzzBUZZfizzBUZZbuzzFIZZbuzzBUZZfizz"
```

**Explanation:**

Fairly straightforward, take the input string, cast into ASCII values, create a list of 1 or 0 depending whether it is odd or even (hint A=65=odd), then use this list to index into a list of `fizz` and `buzz`. Cast this to a string, and then for cases where the input is <91 (lower than a Z) we apply the `upper` function to get a `FIZZ` or a `BUZZ`.

q is interpreted right to left:

```
raze{@[string `fizz`buzz x mod 2;where x < 91;upper]}"i"$ / ungolfed version
                                                     "i"$ / cast input to ascii values
    {                                               }     / anonymous lambda
     @[                         ;            ;     ]      / apply 
                                              upper       / upper-case
                                 where x < 91             / indices where input is less than 91 (ie uppercase)
                         x mod 2                          / returns 0 if even and 1 if odd
              `fizz`buzz                                  / 2 item list, which we are indexing into
       string                                             / cast symbols to strings `buzz -> "buzz"
raze                                                      / raze (merge) list into a single string
```

Comment: I don't know this language, but can you remove the space between `mod` and `2`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it *could* be written it as `mod[x;2]` if we didn't want any whitespace - but that winds up being 1 byte more!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61+1 = 62 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```ruby
gsub(/./){k=$&.ord%2*4;$&<?_?"FIZZBUZZ"[k,4]:"fizzbuzz"[k,4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyvrFgEpBR0C/6nF5cmaejr6WtWZ9uqqOnlF6WoGmmZWKuo2djH2yu5eUZFOYVGRSlFZ@uYxFoppWVWVSWVVlVB@LX//zvnp6S65@ekAQA)